# sine wave to square wave using LT1017

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, sine, square

I am trying to convert sine wave of 50 Hz and 10 mV to square wave of 10 mV of positive side only.

I used the following circuit. But the square wave has higher voltage compare to my requirement.

What changes are need to make in this circuit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Several points:LT1017 needs a minimum supply of 1.5V.  It also has a typical saturation voltage of 5mv, so your output is unlikely to be from 0V to 10mv. Your input is shown as 100mV but the question is for 10mV

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you are operating the LT1017 with a supply voltage of 200mV and the simulation says you get an output voltage of 312mV? Is this Multisim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simulator is lying to you. The [LT1017](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/10178ff.pdf) cannot operate on a power supply of just 200 mV. It needs a minimum of 1.1 V.

Therefore, you need to take the full-swing output that it produces and attenuate it back down to the level you require.